# Reduce query complexity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this multi join query, is there any way to reduce the number of joins? Or maybe to split the query to 2 parts but then still get the same result set? 
Having too many joins makes the query execute very slowly and inefficently

```
SELECT  
    MD.EVENT_ID,
    AUI.ATLAS_USER_ID,
    EVENT_TIME, 
    EVENT_TYPE, 
    INTERACTION_TOKEN, 
    CC.COUNTRY_CODE, 
    AP.ADV_PROJECT_ID, AP.ADV_PROJECT_NAME, 
    AC.ADV_CAMPAIGN_ID,
    ADV_CAMPAIGN_NAME,
    PC.PRT_CAMPAIGN_ID, PC.PRT_CAMPAIGN_NAME,
    IP.IP_ADDRESS, 
    OS.OS, 
    BR.BROWSER, 
    FU.FULL_USER_AGENT, 
    RAW_ACTION_ID, 
    SE.SELLER_NETWORK_ID,
    RIURL.RAW_INPUT as URL,
    RIREF.RAW_INPUT as REF_URL,
    MVG1.MAP_VALUE as    TABOOLA   ,    
    MVG2.MAP_VALUE as    APPNEXUS          ,
    MVG3.MAP_VALUE as    ETAG              ,
    MVG4.MAP_VALUE as    FACEBOOK          ,
    MVG5.MAP_VALUE as    MEDIAMATH         ,
    MVG6.MAP_VALUE as    COOKIEID          ,
    MVG7.MAP_VALUE as    IDFA              ,
    MVG8.MAP_VALUE as    ADVLOGIN          ,
    MVG9.MAP_VALUE as    OPENX             ,
    MVG10.MAP_VALUE as   ADTRUTH           ,
    MVG11.MAP_VALUE as   GOOGLE            ,
    MVG12.MAP_VALUE as   ANDROID_ADV_ID    ,
    MVG13.MAP_VALUE as   SDGUPI            ,
    MVG15.MAP_VALUE as   RMX                
FROM 
    EVENT_124_2 BASE
INNER JOIN 
    atlas__atlas_events MD ON BASE.EVENT_ID = MD.EVENT_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG1 ON MVG1.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.TABOOLA_HASH
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG2 ON MVG2.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.APPNEXUS_HASH       
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG3 ON MVG3.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.ETAG_HASH           
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG4 ON MVG4.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.FACEBOOK_HASH       
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG5 ON MVG5.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.MEDIAMATH_HASH      
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG6 ON MVG6.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.COOKIEID_HASH       
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG7 ON MVG7.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.IDFA_HASH           
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG8 ON MVG8.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.ADVLOGIN_HASH       
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG9 ON MVG9.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.OPENX_HASH          
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG10 ON MVG10.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.ADTRUTH_HASH        
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG11 ON MVG11.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.GOOGLE_HASH         
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG12 ON MVG12.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.ANDROID_ADV_ID_HASH 
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG13 ON MVG13.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.SDGUPI_HASH         
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__MAP_VALUE MVG15 ON MVG15.MAP_VALUE_GK = BASE.RMX_HASH  
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__ATLAS_USER_ID AUI ON AUI.ATLAS_USER_ID_GK = MD.ATLAS_USER_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    GAYA__ADV_PROJECTS AP ON AP.ADV_PROJECT_ID = MD.ADV_PROJECT_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    GAYA__ADV_CAMPAIGNS AC ON AC.ADV_CAMPAIGN_ID = MD.ADV_CAMPAIGN_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    GAYA__PRT_CAMPAIGNS PC ON PC.PRT_CAMPAIGN_ID = MD.PRT_CAMPAIGN_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__RAW_INPUT RIURL ON RIURL.RAW_INPUT_GK = BASE.URL_HASH
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__RAW_INPUT RIREF ON RIREF.RAW_INPUT_GK = BASE.REF_HASH
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__OS OS ON OS.OS_GK = MD.COUNTRY_CODE
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__COUNTRY_CODE CC ON CC.COUNTRY_CODE_GK = MD.COUNTRY_CODE
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__BROWSER BR ON BR.BROWSER_GK = MD.BROWSER
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__IP_ADDRESS IP   ON IP.IP_ADDRESS_GK = MD.IP_ADDRESS
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__SELLER_NETWORK_ID  SE     ON SE.SELLER_NETWORK_ID_GK = MD.SELLER_NETWORK_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    LOOKUP_STG__FULL_USER_AGENT FU   ON FU.FULL_USER_AGENT_GK = MD.FULL_USER_AGENT
;
```

Comment: It might not be the number of joins.  It might be the lack of a filter anywhere.

Comment: UNION might be a better approach than some of those left joins

Comment: A quite common  approach to limit/avoid join is to denormalize your schema...

Comment: 27 Joins without any WHERE-condition, how big are those tables?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any indexes on your key columns? You might try to put bitmap indexes on each key column in the main fact table and also in the dimension tables. That should give you a considerable speedup.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the number of joins makes the query inefficient. But what you should be looking at is whether the tables that are joined with have the proper indexes in them. You obviously need all those fields from the tables you join with, so you can't simply *not* join with them.

For every `JOIN` you make in the query, verify that there exists an `INDEX` on the field that is joined with. For instance:

```
INNER JOIN 
    atlas__atlas_events MD ON BASE.EVENT_ID = MD.EVENT_ID
```

Does the table `atlas__atlas_events` have an `INDEX` on the `EVENT_ID` column?

You need to verify this for every such `JOIN` in your query. If such an `INDEX` does not exist you should create one.

If you execute this query in SQL Server Management Studio and include the [actual execution plan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms189562.aspx), you will probably already see indications that you are missing indexes.